# Windows forms add dynamic button to a certain panel using a function

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a function called AddButton, i would like it to take a panel argument so it knows to what panel it should add the button.

No clue how to do this as im new to C# and windows forms

```
        private void AddButton(string Type)
        {

            if (Type == "But")
            {
                //string Name, string Text, decimal Price, string ItemName

                ButAmount++;
                string NameCode = "Item"+ButAmount.ToString();

                string Text = Interaction.InputBox("Item naam?", "Geef de item naam", "Nieuw item");
                string PriceStr = Interaction.InputBox("Wat is de prijs van dit item?", "Geef de prijs van het item", "1.3");
                decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceStr);


                LocButx = LocButx + 120;
                if (LocButx >= 460) { LocButx = 0; LocButy = LocButy + 50; }


                // Create a Button object 
                Button NewButton = new Button();

                // Set Button properties
                NewButton.Height = 50;
                NewButton.Width = 120;
                NewButton.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                NewButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                NewButton.Location = new Point(LocButx, LocButy);
                NewButton.Text = Text;
                NewButton.Name = NameCode;
                NewButton.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);

                //add data to tag
                NewButton.Tag = $"{Type}:{Price}:{Text}";

                //NewButton.Tag = AddItem(Price, ItemName);

                // Add a Button Click Event handler
                NewButton.Click += new EventHandler(NewButton_Click);

                //Add buttons to the correct panel

            }
               ...
          }

private void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button btn = sender as Button;
            Button cat = sender as Button;
            //MessageBox.Show(btn.Name + " Clicked");

            //Retreive data from new button tag
            string DataStr = btn.Tag as string;
            string[] Data = DataStr.Split(':');
            string Type = Data[0];

            //Add code for each dynamic button press
            if (Type == "But")
            {
                decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(Data[1]);
                string ItemName = Data[2];

                AddItem(Price, ItemName);
            }
            else if (Type == "Cat")
            {
                string Text = Data[1];
                string NameCode = Data[2];
                int CatAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Data[3]);

                switch (CatAmount)
                {
                    case 1:
                        HidePanels();
                        panelCat1.Visible = true;
                        //AddButton to panel here
                        break;
                    ...
                }
              }
           }
```

I expect in the case 1 i can add AddButton(Type, panelName) that will add my dynamic button to the panelname i enter.

Thank you!

Comment: Your function doesn't take a Panel but a string. You need to create a control : `btn = new Button() {Text= .., }` and add it to the panel's Controls collection: `btn.Parent = yourpanel`;`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
yourPanel.Controls.Add(NewButton);
```